# Parse.com for Android: GetCallback implementation of "done" method

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've just upgraded from Parse 1.8.x to Parse 1.9.0 for Android. I've tracked down some of the changes they've made and updated my project accordingly, but I'm getting an odd error in a couple of places and I'm not sure the best way to "fix" it.

In a couple of places, I'm using `getInBackground` to query for an object where I know its `objectId`. It has been working fine until this upgrade.

Now, I'm getting an error that says:

> Error:(113, 80) error:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method done(Object,Throwable) in ParseCallback2.

So, I tried writing a basic query and calling `getInBackground`, and this is what it gives me using autocomplete:

```
ParseQuery query        = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground("xxxx", new GetCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {

    }
});
```

I'm used to seeing the first method, but the second one is tripping me up. I noticed that Parse has changed something starting with 1.8.3, noting:

> Fixed: Callbacks are no longer abstract classes, but interfaces.

So, I went to the declaration for `GetCallback` (which is a stub source generated from a class file), which shows this:

```
public interface GetCallback <T extends com.parse.ParseObject> extends com.parse.ParseCallback2<T,com.parse.ParseException> {
    void done(T t, com.parse.ParseException e);
}
```

Not terribly surprising, so I went to the `ParseCallback2` declaration (also a stub source generated from a class file), which shows this:

```
interface ParseCallback2 <T1, T2 extends java.lang.Throwable> {
    void done(T1 t1, T2 t2);
}
```

Based on this, I think I can see why the compiler is complaining, but I'm not sure what the correct solution is here.

I also got some messages in my Gradle Build output that say:

> Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
>   Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

I'm not sure if that's related to this issue or not, nor am I sure how to figure out whether they're related.

Basically, I think one of two things has gone wrong. Either:
 1. I have some setting in my app that needs to be updated to re-enable the old functionality, --OR--
 2. Parse has an issue with their newest Android API.

It does not seem like a reasonable solution that Parse is actually going to require me to override 2 **different** `done` methods in the `GetCallback`. Has anyone seen this issue and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the generic parameter as follow:

```
ParseQuery query        = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground("xxxx", new GetCallback() {
```

to

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query        = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.getInBackground("xxxx", new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
```

Comment: `Both methods have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other`